# How does this carry look ahead block work?

Tags: digital-logic, alu, adder, carry-look-ahead

This is a carry look ahead adder :

[image]

This adder is known to calculate one or more carry bits before the sum. From the figure we see that carry look ahead block calculates the carry **C1,C2,C3,C4** . But i don't understand how does it do that ?  How does this block calculate the carry before the sum ?

Comment: there aren't reasonable tags present here

Comment: Write down the truth table for the carry look ahead unit, then try to find a simple circuit. Start with 2 or 3 bits to simplify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That diagram doesn't show the actual carry logic. To see how it works you have to examine that in detail.
The carry logic in a look ahead adder is built so it does not have the intrinsic delay associated with a ripple carry adder, where each carry output is input to the next partial adder stage.
In a carry look ahead adder, the carry logic is calculated at the same time, based *purely* on the inputs. So all the carry signals are generated at the same time, rather than waiting for the previous stages carry calculations to propagate (ripple) through. 
This requires quite a bit of extra logic, but is obviously a lot faster. It's a bit similar to how ripple counters can be improved.
The diagram on page 2 of [this](http://writphotec.com/mano4/Supplements/Carrylookahead_supp4.pdf) document shows the difference between the two carry logics, and [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/lab/CarryLookAhead/CarryLookAheadF01.html) page has an excellent treatment of the subject also.

Comment: The diagram on page 2 explained everything !

Comment: Sadly both links are now dead.